# Google Analytics - What is the percentage of total for?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, sem, pay-per-click

I was tracking my PPC ads in Google Analytics via AdWords acquisition and found out that the cost is $3,039.93. However, I realized that it was only the 98.69% of $3,080.15.

Now, what do you think is the reason why **Google only gets a percentage of the cost and not 100%?**

Please see the image attached or follow the link.

[image: Screenshot]

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Is there sampling involved?

Comment: No, it's the default format of Google Analytics. I'm just wondering why it does not get 100% of the value.

Answer (score 0):

This discrepancy could be attributed to cost data import from another third party advertising engine like facebook.com . Please check you Cost Analysis report under Acquisitions --> Campaigns --> Cost Analysis. Also it would not hurt to look in the Admin tab, under the property column, in the Data Import section to be sure if any cost data is being imported.